# Passing arrays to a function call (Bufer Overflow)

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow

I need to execute a call to cat on a target file using a buffer overflow in a challenge app (can't execute on the stack, but can use libc). For reference, in C this is valid code for what I'm trying to do:

```
int main(void) {
        char * const argv[] = {"cat", "/etc/target/file"};
        char * const envp[] = {NULL};;
        execve("/bin/cat", argv, envp);
}
```

I can load some null-terminated strings up on the target and I've also determined the address of execve. Here's the info I have:

```
"/bin/cat" @ 0xbfffffb9:
"cat" @ 0xbfffffbe
"/etc/target/file" @ 0xbffff96f

execve @ 0x804831c
```

I can overwrite the EIP and following bytes with a string like:

```
"AAAA....AAA" + EIP + [RETURN ADDR] + ARG1 + ARG2 ....
```

In the string above I can replace EIP with the address of execve and jump to the function, but that's where things go sour for me. I've never set up a stack for arrays and couldn't find a google example of using arrays in a classic buffer overflow.

How can I set up the stack with array parameters for my function call? What does my stack need to look like in this case?

Comment: Sorry, but which string are you talking about when you say "I can overwrite the EIP and following bytes with a string like:" ? I can't see where the bof is happening in your code.

Comment: Do you have the source code for where the overflow happens?